# checkbox and textbox

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox, checkbox

there is a checkbox and a textbox. initially the textbox is set disabled and on checking the checkbox the textbox in enabled. i hv tried this but the problem is that it is not working when runat server is added. or  i should  change javascript logic for asp.net standard controls. or can suggest me a beeter way to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var checkbox = $('#htmlChkNotify');
    var textfield = $('#htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress');
        checkbox.click(function() {
            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                textfield.removeAttr('disabled');
                textfield.removeClass("email");
            }
            else {
                textfield.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                textfield.addClass("email");
            }
        });
    });


    </script>

<input type="checkbox"  id="htmlChkNotify"/>
<label for="htmlChkNotify">Notify</label>
<input type="text" id="htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress" disabled="disabled" 
       class="email" style="width:25%" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to get this to work.

1. Use all server side code.
2. In your client side (javascript) code, instead of using the server side `id`, use the `.ClientId` property of the control. So, if your `htmlChkNotify` is server side, you can use `var checkbox = $('#<%=htmlChkNotify.ClientId%>');`

Comment: @kinn - What is not working? I gave two options, and you didn't explain which one didn't work and _what_ exactly didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. add the runat attribute to your textbox
2. Change your 4th line to be 
   var textfield = $('#<%=htmlTxtNotifyemailaddress.ClientID %>');

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

See generated HTML ("view source" in browser)
and check IDs of checkbox and textbox